# Excel VBA - Fill in empty database cells with variable range formula

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I have a database containing "N/A" at different cells, caused by temporary system offline.
I used to fill these "N/A"'s using the formula shown with the image:

As you can see, the datum at columns A are cumulative, so are B and C. The "N/A"s are compensated by spreading the difference between the last reading before the first "N/A" and the first reading after the last "N/A"

The "N/A"'s appear at different points and have varying lengths.

Is there maybe a vba code to help me do this in one click for the entire database?
Thank you sirs for your kind help.

[image]

Comment: VBA can certainly be used to solve this, but I think you need to specify what you are trying to do more clearly. For example, why do you look at N/A cells between B6 and B3? Is it because you have N/A in A4 and A5? You say the values are cumulative, but this is not really clear to me.

Comment: Have you tried anything?  If yes, what happened: if no, why not give it a go and see what happens?

Comment: Oh crap sir my mistake, the formulas use cells from column A, not column B. The data displayed here are power consumption readings, so the next cell value contains the power consumtion from the previous hour + the consumption of the specified hour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try running this VBA code to interpolate the `N/A` values based on numbers above and below:

```
Sub FillNA()

Dim rng As Range, col As Range, a As Range
Set rng = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)

For Each col In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns    
    If Not Intersect(rng, col) Is Nothing Then
        For Each a In Intersect(rng, col).Areas
            If a(1) = "N/A" Then
                a(0).Resize(a.Count + 2).DataSeries Trend:=True
            End If
        Next a    
    End If
Next col

End Sub
```

(If `N/A` appears at the beginning or end of the range you will need to decide how to handle this case and make appropriate adjustments)

Comment: Wow this works incredibly well! Thanks so much! But when I run it the second time (when all N/A's are deleted) it returns an error. Plus, this code is awesome, but I'm really new to excel vba and would like to understand the lines of codes you have used. You should se the code I was working on. It was 10x bigger than yours but would only work on single N/A's with values on top and below

Comment: A good way to start with vba is to turn on the macro recorder. For the example shown, you can select the range `A3:A6` and then choose `Fill > Series > Trend (Check)` to fill the N/A values in `A4:A5`. To select all the N/A's choose `Find & Select > Goto Special > Constants: Text`. The code is based on looping through these values, if there are no N/As you will receive an error message.